# Creating a UI with buttons that run different Python Scripts

Tags: python, user-interface

So I have a touch screen and I want to make a UI similar to the one on the picture. Just 6 congruent buttons. When clicked, each button runs a unique Python script. What I am most ly stuck on is the UI. What should I use to make 6 buttons?

[Sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Emus.png)

Comment: use kivy https://kivy.org/#home , it's designed to be ran on touch screens and pretty easy to use.

Comment: tkinter is the *defacto standard gui library that generally ships with python, and it [doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373458/handle-touchscreen-gesture-in-tkinter) really support multitouch. Individual clicks may work though...